# What is the reason for learning vocabulary without understanding the concept behind it

Tags: terminology, theoretical-linguistics, language-acquisition, vocabulary, study-of-terms

I've recently had a discussion with a friend who said that he believes that putting labels on things kills understanding. Meaning if a person learns a name for something before they learn what it actually means they won't be as motivated to learn its meaning. His (anecdotal) example of this were some people in his economics class who learned the vocabulary very well but didn't know or didn't understand the concepts they were naming. I've noticed a similar phenomenon in other classes as well – usually with complicated concepts or difficult terms.

I was wondering if there is any scientific theory that would back this or if the reason is simply time/stress/&c. – and if there is a theory (ironically) what it is called or where I can find studies/research on this topic.

Comment: Sebau-nu-mu, "before they learn what it actually means" : was it the meaning of USA GDP or GNP, actually to learn with Trump government shutdown?  Even much experience with country economy might not provide the answer, and there is nothing to be ironic about. On the other hand, without thought -- there is no idea. I doubt people would be just tossing labels at one another in any class.

Comment: Well when translating texts you don't necessarily need to know the exact meaning the words so you might doubt it but yes, that does happen. Or they might use the words incorrectly because they don't understand the context. I should have maybe mentioned that this is usually in our translating classes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot learn what something "actually" means, until you know what "it" is – the word. I take it that your interlocutors have some higher standard of subject matter knowledge in mind – not necessarily "enough to teach the class" but at least enough to easily pass the final exam in an advanced version of the class. Thus you would know definitions and various applications of the concept – but their prescription apparently would be that you should not be told the words that the definitions and applications unify. Imagine then taking a phonology class where you first learn a bunch of floating definitions and applications of "rule", "feature", "allophone", "phoneme", "neutralization", "contrast", "minimal pair", "vowel", "nasal" and so on – without know what word goes into the definition and exemplification.

Obviously, the problem is not that people learn words, it's that people learn the word *and very little else*, that is, they don't actually learn how the word is used.

Comment: Thank you; I believe the last sentence made the argument against his theory very clear. Though I also think I might have not formulated my question very well – I did mean people who seemingly only learned the words and had when asked no concept of what it meant. Just a "vague idea of what context they were used in" and then went on to use them incorrectly in translations. But I suppose that's part of the definition.